# Get connection parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a way to access the connection parameters given a `mysqli` connection?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","mydb") ;
```

Now how can I use `$con` to acces the database connection properties?

```
$username = $con->username ???
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you serious? You should keep in mind that every function has its return type, based on that you can call further things. did you checked manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to do this? 
You could save the data in a variable to acces it later instead of using the connection variable.

And no it's impossible to get the data using the $con variable. Try var_dump to see if you could acces a property of an object.